# Is there any Restkit 2.0 Tutorial like raywenderlich?

Tags: restkit

i am learning restkit api. I found a very good [Raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13097/intro-to-restkit-tutorial) restkit tutorial. But it is integrated with Restkit 0.10.1. And i want to learn a RestKit-0.20.0-pre6. If any one has good tutorial like this in iOS. Please share. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Finally Raywenderlich has updated tutorial for new RestKit
http://www.raywenderlich.com/58682/introduction-restkit-tutorial

RestKit 0.20 
http://blog.alexedge.co.uk/introduction-to-restkit-0-20/

Reskit 0.20 tutorial
https://github.com/RestKit/RKGist/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md

Developing RESTful iOS Apps with RestKit by 
Blake Watters
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/restkit_ios-sdk--mobile-4524
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/advanced-restkit-development_iphone-sdk--mobile-5916

http://madeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/01/ios-restkit-tutorial-code-for-version.html

finally always follow :)
https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki

NSScreen is a paid service but its codes are free - 
https://github.com/subdigital/nsscreencast

NSScreencast tutorials -

http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/53-restkit-object-manager

http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/52-restkit-coredata

http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/51-intro-to-restkit-mapping

Comment: Fixing the first link from alexedge: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/832 and then remove the script from the build phases

Comment: check out this site too http://restkit-tutorials.com

Comment: There is a brand new tutorial as of February 2015 on using RestKit with CoreData https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/restkit-tutorial-how-to-fetch-data-from-an-api-into-core-data-9326af750e10

Answer (score 4):

I found code below to work with RestKit 0.20.

The other code found in RayWenderlich's tutorial for Location.m, Location.m, Venue.m, and Venue.h should still be all right.

```
//
//  MasterViewController.m
//  CoffeeShop
//
//
//  Copyright (c) 2013 uihelpers. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
#import "Venue.h"
#import "Location.h"


#define kCLIENTID "REPLACE_WITH_OWN_ID"
#define kCLIENTSECRET "REPLACE_WITH_OWN_SECRET"

@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;
    NSArray *cafeArray;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.foursquare.com/v2"];

    AFHTTPClient * client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    [client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:RKMIMETypeJSON];

    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];

    RKObjectMapping *venueMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Venue class]];
    [venueMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"name" : @"name"
     }];

    RKObjectMapping *locationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Location class]];
    [locationMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"address": @"address", @"city": @"city", @"country": @"country", @"crossStreet": @"crossStreet", @"postalCode": @"postalCode", @"state": @"state", @"distance": @"distance", @"lat": @"lat", @"lng": @"lng"}];

    /*[venueMapping mapRelationship:@"location" withMapping:locationMapping];
    [objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:locationMapping forKeyPath:@"location"];*/

    [venueMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"location" toKeyPath:@"location" withMapping:locationMapping]];



    RKResponseDescriptor * responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:venueMapping
                                                                                    pathPattern:nil
                                                                                    keyPath:@"response.venues"
                                                                                    statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

    NSString *latLon = @"37.33,-122.03";
    NSString *clientID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:kCLIENTID];
    NSString *clientSecret = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:kCLIENTSECRET];

    NSDictionary *queryParams;
    queryParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:latLon, @"ll", clientID, @"client_id", clientSecret, @"client_secret", @"coffee", @"query", @"20120602", @"v", nil];






    [objectManager getObjectsAtPath:@"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search"
                         parameters:queryParams
                            success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation * operaton, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
     {
         //NSLog(@"success: mappings: %@", mappingResult);
         NSArray *result = [mappingResult array];
         cafeArray = [mappingResult array];
         for (Venue *item in result) {
             NSLog(@"name=%@",item.name);
             NSLog(@"name=%@",item.location.distance);

         }
         [self.tableView reloadData];
     }
                            failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation * operaton, NSError * error)
     {
         NSLog (@"failure: operation: %@ \n\nerror: %@", operaton, error);
     }];


}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    if (!_objects) {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return cafeArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    /*NSDate *object = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object description];*/
    Venue *venueObject = [cafeArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [venueObject.name length] > 24 ? [venueObject.name substringToIndex:24] : venueObject.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0fm", [venueObject.location.distance floatValue]];

    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

@end
```

This tutorial might also help:

http://madeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/01/ios-restkit-tutorial-code-for-version.html

Comment: Very nice tutorial. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question and managed to work it out just as someone gave me the answer! Typical!

A quick look here [Restkit 0.20 basic operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737936/restkit-0-20-basic-operation/14769873#14769873)