# Restkit XML Parsing, XML Object Mapping

Tags: ios, xml, restkit-0.20

When I try to parse the xml response am getting below content in my console. Even though I changed the `SerializationMIMEType` as `RKMIMETypeTextXML` result were same.

Any suggestion and help would be greatly appreciated.

```
AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest https://services.walgreens.com/snapfishapi/v2>, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://services.walgreens.com/snapfishapi/v2, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected content type {(
"text/html",
"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"application/json"
)}, got text/xml, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x95357f0>}`
```

Comment: add your parsing code here.

Comment: Please visit this link, I hope you will get what u want 
<http://stackoverflow.com/a/15607217/2261595>

Comment: How and where are you setting the mime type? How are you calling to get the download data? Add the code.