# Building RestKit object hasMany relationships with IDs only

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

Our Web API returns Ember Data compatible objects with relationships defined like so:

```
{containers: [
    {
        id: "12345678",
        name: "name",
        items: [1, 2]
    }
 ],
 items: [
    {
        id: 1
        name: "item 1"
    },
    {
        id: 2
        name: "item 2"
    }
 ]
}
```

Notice that the item IDs are included in the container object, and that each related item is sideloaded in the same call.  Is there any way to set up this kind of relationship with RestKit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foreign key relationship mapping with RestKit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326087/foreign-key-relationship-mapping-with-restkit)

Comment: That works with arrays of keys too

Comment: @Wain Thank you for that.  I found that one but It wasn't clear that it would support arrays of keys as well.  I'll try that one out!

Comment: Yeah, rather than the transient being a string set it to transformable and you should be good.

Comment: @Wain I can't seem to make this work.  One thing of significance is that I am NOT using Core Data object mappings, just normal ones.  All of the examples I find that do this use Core Data classes.  Is it possible to do this without Core Data?

Comment: No. Core data only. The `addConnectionForRelationship` API is on the entity mapping and using core data is the only way RestKit knows how to look up the objects to be connected. Outside core data you need to configure some kind of 'relationship' yourself.

Comment: Core Data it is!  Thanks @Wain