# RestKit mapping relation between two entities when id of an entity is known only in one of the entities

Tags: core-data, mapping, restkit, restkit-0.20, relationships

I have an entity called `Card` that has it's properties. 
The other entity is a `Slide` entity. And it has a one-to-one relation to `Card`.
There is no mention of `Slide` in the JSON that i receive for `Card`, but in the JSON for a `Slide` there is a "cardID" value that is equal to ID of the `Card` entity.

Here is the Card mapping:

```
@"cardID"             : @"cardId",
@"cardTexts"          : @"texts",
```

And a Slide mapping:

```
@"imageID"   : @"imageId",
@"cardID"    : @"cardId",
```

And that is JSON for Slide entities:

```
[
    {"imageID":1619,"cardID":4922},
    {"imageID":1619,"cardID":1332}, 
    etc
]
```

I don't understand how to make a proper relation. Tried to make something like:

```
[slideMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"cardId" toKeyPath:@"card" withMapping: cardMapping]];
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Please point out my mistake

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foreign key relationship mapping with RestKit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326087/foreign-key-relationship-mapping-with-restkit)

Comment: You need to use foreign key mapping. The type of relationship you're using is for nested data mapping.