# RestKit using RKConnectionDescription to sideload data

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, restkit

I'm using RestKit and I cannot figure out the way to make the mapping work. I have a `Playlist` Managed Object which has many `Beat` Managed Objects.

```
let playlistMapping = RKEntityMapping(forEntityForName: "Playlist", inManagedObjectStore: appDelegate.managedObjectStore)
playlistMapping.identificationAttributes = ["playlistId"]
playlistMapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary(["id" : "playlistId", "name" : "name", "beats" : "beatIds"])

let beatMapping = RKEntityMapping(forEntityForName: "Beat", inManagedObjectStore: appDelegate.managedObjectStore)
beatMapping.identificationAttributes = ["beatId"]
beatMapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary(["id" : "beatId", "name" : "name"])

playlistMapping.addConnectionForRelationship("playlistBeats", connectedBy: ["beatIds" : "beatId"])

let statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)
let playlistResponseDescriptor = RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: playlistMapping, method: RKRequestMethod.Any, pathPattern: "/playlists/:id", keyPath: "playlist", statusCodes: statusCodes)

let beatResponseDescriptor = RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: beatMapping, method: RKRequestMethod.Any, pathPattern: "/beats/:id", keyPath: "beats", statusCodes: statusCodes)
```

Here's the JSON

```
{
    "playlist": {
        "id": "top-rated",
        "beats": [
            "180574",
            "181515"
        ]
    },
    "beats": [
        {
            "id": "180574",
            "producer": "14649",
            "name": "On The Hunt"

        },
        {
            "id": "181515",
            "producer": "14649",
            "name": "Anatomy"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here are the Managed Objects

```
@interface Playlist : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * playlistId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id beatIds;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *playlistBeats;
@end


@interface Beat : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * beatId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Producer *producer;
@end
```

When I run this I get the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot connect relationship:
>   invalid attributes given for source entity 'Playlist': beats'

**EDIT**:

I have already read this answer: [Foreign key relationship mapping with RestKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326087/foreign-key-relationship-mapping-with-restkit) but I do not understand how to make it work for my particular JSON data.

I already have a `NSSet *beats` attribute in the `Playlist` Managed Object.

Where in the issue in the other question they have single `Team` for each `User` - I have multiple `Beats` for each `Playlist`.

**EDIT 2:**

Ok I've added a transient attribute `beatIds` in the `Playlist` entity which is of `Transformable` type. I've mapped it to hold the array of `beat` id's in the `playlist` object. Now the app doesn't crash any more but I don't think it's processing the relationship correctly.

```
<Playlist: 0x10dae81b0> (entity: Playlist; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://F9813F68-CBAD-4947-81B5-C126E3BF33D9/Playlist/p1> ; data: {
    beatIds = nil;
    name = nil;
    playlistBeats = "<relationship fault: 0x10dae6f10 'playlistBeats'>";
    playlistId = "top-rated";
})
```

Comment: Have you checked whether the JSON `beats` collection is being built as a `NSSet` or `NSArray`?

Comment: If i'm understanding you correctly then the `beats` collection is an `NSSet` as defined in the `Playlist : NSManagedObject` code above. Is this what you mean?

Comment: You are missing the transient (on Playlist) which holds the ids to map. In the other answer it is a single item, in your case it is an array. Other than that the process is the same.

Comment: @Wain please see edit, i've added a transient on the `Playlist` object called `beatsIds` and mapped it to the `beats` array in the JSON data. This still doesn't seem to be making the relationship correctly. I've edited the code above, appreciate your help.

Comment: You want the property to be an `NSArray`. Have you tested accessing the relationship and looked at the mapping trace log?

Comment: @Wain it appears to be working but only when I request it a second time. Within the block `operation.setCompletionBlockWithSuccess({ (operation: RKObjectRequestOperation!, result: RKMappingResult!) in` I locate the `Playlist` object and try to access it's `playlistBeats` property. It's a relationship error on the first operation run, but if I run the operation again it contains all the `Beat` objects. Why would it do that?

Comment: You access the mapping result to check this? It shouldn't. The server result could be wrong, or you could be accessing a disconnected context, hard to know - now you have resolved the foreign key mapping you should probably create a new question for other issues and show the incoming data and mapping results...