# RestKit Varying Root Objects in POST

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I'm posting to the web services a string that represents store ID and I'm receiving data in the following format:

```
{
    "status": {
        "code": 201,
        "message": "Session created"
    },
    "session": "a1e0f68e82ca4d0095d4b2a9582c7e21",
    "store": {
        "id": 62,
        "code": "123",
        "name": "ABCD",
        "address1": "address line 1",
        "address2": "address line 2",
        "currencyCode": "USD",
    },
    "employees": [
        {
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

I've passed on some response descriptors like so:

For session object:

```
RKObjectMapping *sessionMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Session class]];
[sessionMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"session" : @"token"}];
RKResponseDescriptor *sessionDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:sessionMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:201]];
```

For store object:

```
RKEntityMapping *storeMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Store"
                                                    inManagedObjectStore:[[DataModel sharedDataModel] objectStore]];
[storeMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"code" : @"code", @"id" : @"uuid", @"name" : @"name", @"address1" : @"address1", @"address2" : @"address2", @"currencyCode" : @"currencyCode"}];
storeMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"code"];
storeMapping.deletionPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"deleted = true || open = false"];
RKResponseDescriptor *storeDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:storeMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

And similar as above for employee objects.

Then this is how I run the operation:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[sessionDescriptor, storeDescriptor, usersDescriptor]];

RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:myPath parameters:parameters];
operation.targetObject = nil; //as per https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) 
{
    successBlock(mappingResult);
}  failure:nil];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
```

The issue is that while Session and Employees are built fine, I cannot get the store object to show up. Nothing is mapped!

Furthermore, the stores actually already all insist as objects from a previous call, but they only have a code and a name. This call is supposed to populate the remaining fields.

The second part of my question is that obviously in the response the employees and the store are both root-level objects. The store object also has employees as a property. So somehow I need to map what comes back in the employees array to the store object. Is there a way to do this with a descriptor or do I need to manually do this in the success completion block?

Answer (score 1):

Your store response descriptor should have the key path set to `store`. Also, the response descriptor is linked to the `RKRequestMethodGET` method, but you make the server request with `RKRequestMethodPOST`.

Note that you probably shouldn't be using `deleted` in your predicate (take caution with naming clashes with managed objects).

Look at [foreign key mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326087/foreign-key-relationship-mapping-with-restkit) to connect relationships between non-nested content.

Comment: Hm, thanks for the reply. I tried setting the key path, but that didn't work. Thanks for the link for how to link two entities though. Upvote for that :))