# using restkit do you have to remap EVERYTHING each time something changes?

Tags: ios, database, restkit

Right now I have a server that formats my data exactly how restkit wants it, and restkit just takes it and directly maps it to coredata.

This works fine, but when I start to accumulate a lot of data it becomes slow.

For example, I have one object called "stories" and each story contains an array of "posts". each time a new "post" gets added, I regenerate the "story" object to which the new post belongs to, and return the story object to the user for restkit to map. As a story starts to accumulate many posts, this process becomes very slow for restkit. I would prefer a way to just send back new posts, and then tell restkit "hey, add this post to the array of posts on this story", which is in contrast to what I do now which is more like "replace this story with this one I just returned, which includes all posts including any new or updated ones".

Is this possible within restkit? Am I better served just manipulating core data myself to support updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

You can look at 'foreign key mapping' to connect your new posts to the existing story. The most important part is to set the [relationship assignment type](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKRelationshipMapping.html#//api/name/assignmentPolicy) to Union because the default is replace.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326087/foreign-key-relationship-mapping-with-restkit